# How to start app without navigating to its directory

Tags: python, console

I've looked around for an answer to this, but i don't know how to phrase it in a way that google will understand.

I'm trying to learn Python, and i've installed it on my machine. However, when i just type "python" in cmd.exe, the python app is not found/launched.

I have to manually go to the directory in which python.exe is found in order to run my python commands. Is this normal? Online tutorials seem to indicate that I should be able to run the app from anywhere :s

I'm on Win7, and trying to run Python from the Django stack by BitNami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognised-as-a-command

Add python to your environment path. You should then be able to use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your python installation folder to environment variable "PATH"? More details you can find here: http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html