# Selenium with GhostDriver in Python on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

This is embarrassing to ask because it seems like something with so slim chance of error. I wouldn't think this would be difficult, but I've been plugging away at this for almost 3 hours now and it's giving me a headache. I've read several dozen stackoverflow threads and Google threads.

I've installed PhantomJS, added it to my System Variables PATH, and it works properly in the command line. I also installed Selenium earlier with easy_install.

The error I get is:

```
__init__    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py   50      

start   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py 66      

WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\Python27\misc\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe")
```

I also tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

I get the same error message. This has to be something simple that I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate any comments or answers.

Windows 7 64 bit
Python 2.7

Comment: Yes, I copied that path and pasted it, no mistakes. I also just ran it in command line and it changed to "phantomjs>". So all is well there. I'm thinking it may be a version mismatch or something? This is really stumping me.

Comment: 1.9.7. Path is: C:\Python27\misc\phantomjs\

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Please try put into another path and try again. The error message says path is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that before posting. So strange. When I said version mismatch, I was thinking between Selenium and PhantomJS but they're both freshly installed today.

Comment: It's getting stranger. I changed every / to // and then ran the unsaved python script in pyscripter and it gave me the error: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ghostdriver.log'. Which I think is progress. Then I saved it, and the error came back. This problem has something to do with references of the path, or how the path is being interpreted.

Comment: I tried running 'phantomjs --webdriver = 5000' and a bunch of random ports, but it says "Can't open '5000'"

Comment: I think it's a bug: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6736

Comment: hmm, Permission denied: 'ghostdriver.log' you say? from where were you executing your python script? most likely PhantomJS didn't have permissions to create a file in that directory, see my answer on how to prevent PhantomJS from making a ghostdriver.log file

Answer (score 13):

This may have been a version issue for you, but since I just went through setting this up on my Windows 7 PC without issues I'm going to share my 'journey' here.

First of, I'm more used to the Mac/Linux Terminal and having the python package manager `pip` at my disposal is essential to me. After installing [Python 2.7.8](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/) and adding `;c:\Python27` [to my PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054429/2401628) I noticed that `pip` isn't included with Python versions lower than 2.7.9, so I [had to add it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/2401628). Afterwards I added `;c:\Python27\Scripts` to my PATH.

After that fetching the python package `selenium` was as easy as typing the following into the cmd:

```
pip install selenium
```

Then I downloaded the `phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip` from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), unzipped it and placed it here:

```
C:\Python27\misc\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe
```

From there I had a working Python 2.7/Selenium Webdriver/PhantomJS example for Windows 7.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

phantomjs_path = "C:\Python27\misc\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path, service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.set_window_size(1400, 1000)

browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")

print browser.title
```

Note that I added the argument `service_log_path=os.path.devnull` to the function `webdriver.PhantomJS()` to prevent PhantomJS from creating a ghostdriver.log in the directory of the python file being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running Python 3.4 on Windows Server 2012 R2. PhantomJS was failing to create the ghostdriver.log file. I followed these steps that fixed it for me:

- Made sure phantomjs.exe was not showing "Blocked" on the File Properties|Security tab, and ran it as standalone app to confirm.
- **Deleted an old copy of the ghostdriver.log file** that was in the same directory.
- Ran python REPL from the console while checking to see if the code that instantiated the driver was getting called successfully.

  ```
  browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='phantomjs.exe', desired_capabilities=argdc, service_args=svc_args)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you any other file or directory with a same name , or a file of coding (like .. phantomjs.py) which you have named same as `phantomjs` is so then rename it to something else. i hope it works