# Where to place PhantomJS exe?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS with Selenium and Python.

My understanding is:

> I will have to write Python script utilizing Selenium package which will interact with Selenium to operate on PhantomJS WebDriver to automate web application testing.

I have installed following:

- Python v3.5.1.
- Selenium using `pip install selenium` v3.7.0.
- PhantomJS v2.1.1

In meantime I tested using Chrome WebDriver by placing it in PATH, and it executes without errors. Following is my script to open google.com using chrome webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or add to your PATH
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

**Using PhantomJS:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.google.com"
path_phantom = r'H:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path_phantom)
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot(r'H:\out.png')
driver.quit()
```

**Errors:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\testing\openYoutube.py", line 5, in 
>       driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>     File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-package
>   s\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 51, in **init**
>       log_path=service_log_path)
>     File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-package
>   s\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 50, in **init**
>       service.Service.**init**(self, executable_path, port=port, log_file=open(log
>   _path, 'w'))
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ghostdriver.log'

Am I misplacing PhantomJS exe or missing any step ?

Comment: place it anywhere but just ensure it is available in environment path and you're getting permission error so where ever it is present it is not able create a log file I would recommend to place it in such directory where administrator  rights are not required

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `PhantomJS v2.1.1` binary at any location within your system and use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.url.com.br/contact.asp"
path_phantom = r'C:\your_path\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path_phantom)
driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
driver.get(url)
```

### Update :

Please consider the following points and try the following code block with debug messages:

- Run `CCleaner` tool to wipe off all the `OS` chores from your system.
- You can opt for a `System Reboot`.
- Try to keep the `Python` Application, `WebBrowser` binaries and the `WebDriver` binaries i.e. `phantomjs.exe` on the same drive.

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  url = "http://www.google.com"
  path_phantom = r'C:\Utility\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path_phantom)
  print("PhantomJS browser invoked")
  driver.get(url)
  print("Browser Initialized")
  driver.save_screenshot("C://Utility//out.png")
  driver.quit()
  print("Browser Closed")
  ```

Comment: Is my understanding of working with all these tools correct ?

Comment: Well, Yes you are. But as I keep on using different versions of the `webdriver` binaries, I would suggest to get explicit. Rather relying on the `OS` to help you find the `webdriver` binaries while using `Chrome`, `Gecko`, `IE` or `PhantomJS` WebDrivers, we can help ourselves specifying the absolute path too.

Comment: I followed your answer. But problem persists.

Comment: @Rahul Can you update the Question with your current code block & full error stack trace?

Comment: Check now. Errors are same as before.

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158657/discussion-between-rahul-and-debanjanb).

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with the log file.

Changing path of log file solved this problem.

```
path_phantom = r'H:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe'
log_path=r'H:\ghostdriver.log'  #changed path to a temporary file.
# service_log_path is required to change path of log file.
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path_phantom,service_log_path=log_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ghostdriver.log

Seems that it try to create this file `ghostdriver.log` but fails because of the permissions.

As suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24579327/3881320), try to add the argument

```
service_log_path=os.path.devnull
```

to the function `webdriver.PhantomJS()`.

Or make sure it is able to create the file.