# Installing python modules designed for older versions

Tags: python

I'm running Python 2.7.6 and wanting to install several modules that haven't been updated so are still designed for python 2.5.  Is there a way to install these older modules on newer versions of python, or do I just have to install an older version of python (i.e. 2.5) on my PC? (Just to confirm I'm running windows 7)

Comment: It depends on the module.  If the module is written in pure Python it will probably still just work.  If it has parts written in C then it would need to be updated.  What are the modules you're looking at?

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm specifically trying to use pyTTS which I think (but I may well be wrong) has parts written in C

Comment: For that, it looks like there may be more recent work here: https://github.com/parente/pyttsx .  In general, your best bet may be to try installing whatever modules you need (using pip, say), and then ask questions for each one if installation fails.  The reasons that a library wouldn't work on a newer version could differ for each library (e.g., it may work itself, but depend on other libraries that aren't updated).

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn.  I'm working with Dragonfly at present instead and I'm trying to work with that.  For some reason when I open pip, it opens and closes almost instantly.  Don't know why (I have installed it of course)

Comment: @BrenBarn sorry to be a pain, but I've downloaded the files from that github link, but how do I install it wit pip not working?

Comment: You can try `python setup.py install`

Comment: @BrenBarn where do I write that?  When I go into cmd it doesn't recognise python

Comment: This is getting rather far afield from your original question.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognised-as-a-command).  If you continue to have problems with installing modules, you should search for questions about the errors you encounter, and/or ask a new question that is specific to the problem you come across.

Comment: @BrenBarn sorry and I appreciate how we've traversed some distance from the original question.  Thanks so much for the link, I think it may be working now!