# 'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, robotframework

I installed `Python2.7.12` and then installed robotframework using the below command

```
python -m pip install robotframework
```

it showed the result as installed successfully.

When i have given the command `pybot --version`
it showed as

```
'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

In environment variables python home set as C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts are set.

Please any can help me what can be reason for error

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: Add python executable path to the Windows PATH variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognised-as-a-command

Comment: Does `pybot.bat` works?

Comment: Thanks @JohnMayer, i already added python executable path to windows path variable, but still not worked. one of the solution in that question.  `c:\python27\tools\scripts\win_add2path.py` solved the issue

Comment: @JohnMayer, pybot command is working only in the directory where python is installed i.e.,`c:\python27`; if it is outside then getting the same error as above. can you please help on this

Comment: Do you see this path in your machine? C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot, this is the place where it gets called from. Also check if you have multiple python versions installed and to which is robot linked to. Make sure to add that one under windows PATH

Comment: Thanks @Waman, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **python 3**, use `robot` instead of `pybot`

*All thanks to @saurav*

Answer (score 5):

Need to setup following in the environment variable PATH

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot;
C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\bin;
```

Thanks for your help JohnMayer and Waman.

It is working fine now

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Comment: For python 3, use robot instead of pybot (my python version is 3.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

Following steps worked for me:

1. Add C:\Python27\Scripts to the path environment variable
2. Create pybot.bat file inside above location and put **robot %*** this content.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason there is no pybot.bat file, then create a pybot.bat file. Inside this file add **robot %*** and place the file in a directory reached from %PATH - 
https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/1468#issuecomment-366524912

Comment: Perhaps you could improve the formatting of your post.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

along with below values in System Variables' PATH variable.

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot;
C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\bin;
```

Only then it worked.

Also every time you update environment variables you need to relaunch your cmd/powershell window or reload environment variables for changes to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

setup following in the environment variable PATH
C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot;
and also browser.exe path

Worked for me.