# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file using PHP passthru()

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to invoke my python script from php by using passthru() function. I have already done that successfuly and for development I used xampp , now at some moment I  installed manually apache,php and other add-ons.
I also made changes to apache conf to make my python scripts work, some of them work when i invoke them directly via ajax,but scripts like this:

```
<?php

passthru("python C:/Apache24/htdocs/app1/pyscripts/export_zakup.py GARČIN
2>&1",$retval);
echo $retval;

?>
```

give me result like:
**'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 1**

Also when i copy python C:/Apache24/htdocs/app1/pyscripts/export_zakup.py GARČIN to my cmd it works properly.
I have already spent few hours trying to find out where the problem is but unsuccessfuly. Anyone knows where the problem is?

Comment: It means there is no `pyton` global executable. Maybe add it to your PATH var or call directly

Comment: @Justinas how it isn't if I can call python from my cmd no matter in which folder I am positioned?

Comment: Can you check this in CMD python --version

Comment: Have you added python env variable in windows all user or current user ?

Comment: @Googlian yes I get output Python 3.7.0 :\

Comment: @Googlian all users

Comment: Try putting the full path to the Python executable.

Comment: Where is your python located ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard now it works. Thanks !!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for advice !

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["python" not recognized as a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognized-as-a-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, locate where the Python executable is by runniing `which python` from the command line:

```
$ which python
$ /usr/bin/python
```

Then use the full path to the executable in your PHP script:

```
passthru("/usr/bin/python C:/Apache24/htdocs/app1/pyscripts/export_zakup.py GARČIN
2>&1",$retval);
echo $retval;
```

Keep in mind that the path will be different on Windows vs. Linux based machines. For example the latest versions on Windows typically install the executable in `C:\Python27\`, so the full path would be `C:\Python27\python`