# Error in cmd as python version not showing

Tags: cmd, command, prompt

While i write

```
python --version
```

I get nothing as a result in command prompt. I should get the version details of python, correct? how to rectify it?

Its the same for pip also, which file to download and how to install them, .whl or .grz? The guide shows method using pip --version which again is not working in cmd at the first place.

Comment: "I get nothing as a result".  That seems rather unlikely.  Are you saying that you open a cmd window, type in what you have, hit enter, and that nothing is displayed on screen except the command prompt?

Comment: Exactly, when i type 'python - - version', hit enter, control goes to next line ready for next command...

Comment: it rather opens microsoft app store

Comment: I believe that means you don't have python installed.

Comment: I have python installed, it's 3.7. Also this python is the interpreter in pycharm!

Comment: You can see if this helps you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognized-as-a-command

Comment: Seeing it, thanx.

Comment: my command: setx path C:\Users\CG-DTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python &

OutPut: SUCCESS: Specified value was saved._________________________________________________(intentional space)____________________________________________I've also added  C:\Users\CG-DTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python in environment variable path as recommended by the link you shared, but no help :(.

Comment: and now it has started to show me ''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: it was solved, thanx for the help :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say how your issue was solved, so I had to figure it out myself. 
My problem was a 0kb Python.exe in the WindowsApps folder, which is in the PATH environmental variable. I just deleted that file, and everything worked.

Comment: I am sorry, it worked just on a restart. Some cache problems maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I found entering `python --version` in terminal didn't work either, but entering `py --version` did.

Comment: same for me.  python exe in path etc by python --version is blank, py --version shows correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I fixed the problem by adding the python.exe directory to environment variables

```
Open System Properties (Right click Computer in the start menu, or use the keyboard shortcut Win+Pause)
Click Advanced system settings in the sidebar.
Click Environment Variables...
Select PATH in the System variables section
Click Edit

Add Python's path to the end of the list (the paths are separated by semicolons). For example:

C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27
```