# VS Code python troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio, python-requests

I installed the VS Code, then i installed Python and Code Runner (according to tutorial on web) in.
I launched the VS Code and I typed `print("say Hello")` and i got a problem (see a pic). Nevertheless i run the code and i got this:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Windows\System32\hello\hello.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What's wrong?

Problem in code:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPA2o.png

Comment: Sharing information in screenshots is discouraged, please only do so if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['python' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: No it didn't help me.

Comment: How is that possible? Isn't that what the accepted answer is?

Comment: The first answer at this question helped me fix it. So i commented it wrong. It could help me, but first i looked at that answer. Sorry. But your comment was helpfull, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add Python to your environment variables so your computer can recognize the code being run.

Here is a short tutorial showing how you can add python to your environment variables: https://appuals.com/fix-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: Thanks, my old code works now. I typed to terminal in VS Code `pip install pipenv` and I have got the same problem, but instead of `'python'` i have `'pip'`. What's wrong again?

Comment: dont forget to upvote :) You need to now install pip and likley add that to your path

Answer (score 1):

Either Python is not properly installed or you should add python to Window's path variable (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognized-as-a-command) S/O question). Does that help you?