# Running a simple local HTTP server using Python 3.x

Tags: python, windows

I'm following this help page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server

I'm running Windows 10 and Python 3.7.8. I created a folder where I want a test environment. Then I changed the directory in the command prompt to that folder and ran the command to start up the server.
`C:\Users\jpilbeam\TestEnvironment>python3 -m http.server`

But that did not work, and neither did the alternative port 7800:
`Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`

I know I have a couple copies of Python 3.x on my machine. From the terminal I only found one using this:`python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"`

Prints:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64`

Based on that help doc, I'm not able to set up the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to FluxedScript, I did the following workflow to get it to work:
(1) Windows start menu --> typed in environment variables
(2) In System Properties menu I clicked Environment Variables
(3) In the System variables window of the Environment Variables menu I highlighted Path and clicked Edit
(4) I clicked New then entered: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64` ---> then clicked OK on all menus

Back in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\jpilbeam>cd C:\Users\jpilbeam\TestEnvironment

C:\Users\jpilbeam\TestEnvironment>py -V
Python 3.7.8

C:\Users\jpilbeam\TestEnvironment>python3 -m http.server ###this did not work!

C:\Users\jpilbeam\TestEnvironment>python -m http.server ###this did work!
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure python is added to your environment paths. If you are not sure how to do this you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognized-as-a-command) or uninstall and reinstall Python and make sure to tick the box where it says add to environment paths.

Try doing `python --version` and if it comes up your environment path has been set.

Try using `python -m http.server` instead.