# How Can I Solve Symphony/Process Error at Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hello I would like to execute python program at my laravel controller with symphony/process package. I installed python3.6 to the project file. And even though I install symphony/process with composer, I' m taking error like

> 'The command "C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\PythonTestapi\Python36\python.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\PythonTestapi\app\Http\Controllers\Api\CustomVideo.py" failed.Exit Code: -1073740791(Unknown error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp..\public Output:Error Output:Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python'.

Whatever I made, I didn' t solve the problem. Can you give me an idea for fixing it? Thank you in advance..

```
       public function store(Request $request) {
            $process = new Process(['C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\PythonTestapi\Python36\python.exe', app_path('Http\Controllers\Api\CustomVideo.py')]);
            $process->setTimeout(3600);
            $process->run();
            if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            }
            $pyResult = $process->getOutput();

            return throw new HttpResponseException(response([
                'status' => true,
                'result' => $pyResult
            ], HttpStatus::HTTP_OK));
        }
```

Comment: Try using the full path to the python executable. Python isn't in the PATH for the user running the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["python" not recognized as a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054424/python-not-recognized-as-a-command)

Comment: I tried like 'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe', but the problem was continue..

Comment: "but the problem was continue" - what does that mean? Neither `C:\...\app` nor `C:\Users\..\AppData` look like valid paths to me

Comment: I recommend that you install python globally on the machine where the server is, because if you put a static local path it may not be the same on the server.

Comment: @MrEduar I installed python under the project file like 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\..\Python36\python.exe' but I' m getting error when controller executed. The command C:\xampp..CustomVideo.py\" failed.Exit Code: -1073740791(Unknown error)\n\nWorking directory: Error Output: Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

Comment: Please ad all clarification **to your question** by editing it, especially if you're facing a new error message

Comment: @RCeyda As I **clearly mentioned before**, install it globally on your machine. And make sure that from a terminal you can execute python

Comment: @MrEduar I installed python with installer to main path or project path. I can execute python code with cmd/admnstrator. But python program doesn't executed with process in Laravel project.